# Q promises - How does scope work?

Tags: javascript, scope, q

How does the scope of the Q promises work? As far as I know the callback of the "then" is called by window, like a setTimeout.

In this example (just an example to understand how it works):

```
var getFileText = function() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    Server.readFile("foo.txt", "utf-8", function (error, text) {
        if (error) {
            deferred.reject(new Error(error));
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(text);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};

var Foo =  function () {
    getFileText().then(this.showFile);
};

Foo.prototype.showFile = function(text) {
    this.text = text;
    console.log(text);
};

var foo = new Foo();
```

To have the text in the instance of foo I'm using bind:

```
var Foo =  function () {
    getFileText().then(this.showFile.bind(this));
};
```

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How does the scope of the Q promises work?

You're looking for the *context*.

> I know the callback of the "then" is called by window

Well, *on* the global context, yes. It [is specified](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec) to be called with `undefined` as the `thisArg`.

> I'm using bind. Is there any other way?

Only the lengthy one, with a variable referencing the instance:

```
var that = this;
getFileText().then(function(text) {
    that.text = text;
    // or even longer:
    // that.showFile(text);
});
```

Comment: `Q.nbind()` helped me with this issue as described here https://github.com/kriskowal/q#adapting-node

Comment: @Tulio: `nbind` is not supposed to be used for `then` callbacks, but for promisifying object methods.